# Firebase date type field conversion

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore

I am receiving data from firestore in the below format of the field whose type is Date.

```
{
    "seconds": 1642512053,
    "nanoseconds": 303000000
}
```

Above value is saved in firestore as

```
January 18, 2022 at 6:58:19 PM UTC+5:30
```

I want to display the value in `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm AMPM`; however `toDate, DatePipe, formatDate`... none method works. I did string conversion and then converted it to date from seconds which is too much tedious.

Has anyone faced a similar problem and any short-cut trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those pipes take milliseconds. You could do something like this:

class:

```
  data = {
    "seconds": 1642512053,
    "nanoseconds": 303000000
  };
```

html:

```
{{ data.seconds * 1000 + data.nanoseconds / 1000000 | date: 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm a' }}
```

Which at the time of writing this outputs: `18/20/2022 08:20 AM`.

Here's a stackblitz showcasing it:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c2u4ms?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Thanks for making life simple.

Comment: How do I convert the data of received in Date type into Jason as you described? As I said earlier, although it is in Date data type, it doesn't support formatting. Neither it supports "data.seconds".